# discord.py - How can i make a slash command's response only visible to me?

Tags: python, discord.py

With discord.py, how can I make a slash command only visible to me?
example:[image: example of limited visibility command]

The only thing I found in my internet searches was how to make a slash command. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@bot.tree.command(name="something")
async def something(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("NOTHING",ephemeral=True)
    # optional (if you want to edit the response later,delete it, or send a followup)
    await interaction.edit_original_response(content="Something")
    await interaction.followup.send("This is a message too.",ephemeral=True)
    await interaction.delete_original_response()
    # if you have deleted the original response you can't edit it or send a followup after it
```

And these are the basics. If you don't know how to load the commands:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online!")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} commands.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

All set! Good luck with coding. If you need further help my discord is @rexy.py

Comment: i've never expected everything to be here lol, thanks :)